# When reading B/W image as Numpy array using OpenCV I get different results than reading as an image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, hdf5

My end-user is reading images, converting them to greyscale and packaging them into H5 files as numpy arrays using the following code:

```
image = Image.open(imageFilename)
greyscaleImage = image.convert("L")
imageData = np.asarray(greyscaleImage)
    if convertTo16Bit:
        imageData16bit = imageData.astype(np.uint16)
        imageData16bit = imageData16bit*8
        imageData = imageData16bit

h5Filename = makeFilename(imageId, appendToName)
h5FullPath = os.path.join(filePath, h5Filename)
h5file = h5py.File(h5FullPath, "w")
dset = h5file.create_dataset("image", data=imageData)
```

I then read these H5 files as follows:

```
        if args.file_types == 'image':
            image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(args.input, filename), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            
        elif args.file_types == 'h5, hdf5':
            hf = h5py.File(os.path.join(args.input, filename), "r")
            key = list(hf.keys())[0]
            data = np.array(hf[key])
            hf.close()
            image = cv2.cvtColor(np.uint16(data), cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
            plt.axis('off')
            plt.imshow(image)
            plt.show()
```

I need to convert to RGB to then use them in an object detection model.
When I read the H5 files and view the images they have lost information and the model does not perform detection as well as when using the original jpgs.

Please can someone help me to understand how I can read the H5 files without losing any information?

Comment: It's hard to work out what you are really trying to do. You start off with an image and it is unclear whether that is colour or greyscale and whether it is 8 or 16-bit. You then discard all the colour information - why? You then multiply it by 8 for no obvious reason which won't make it any better or more 16-bit than it was before. Then you write it into hdf5 - why? Then you try and pretend it's colour when it isn't... Maybe you could explain from first principles what you start with and what you want at the end. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, information is missing from your HDF5 file because the user converted the image to gray scale (with `image.convert("L")`). Your image goes from 3 channels to 1 channel when you do this. Example code below demonstrates this.

```
image = Image.open(imageFilename)
print(image.size,image.mode)
image.show()
imageData = np.asarray(image)
print('Color image:',imageData.dtype, imageData.shape)

greyscaleImage = image.convert("L")
print(greyscaleImage.size,image.mode)
greyscaleImage.show()
imageData = np.asarray(greyscaleImage)
print('Grey scale image:',imageData.dtype, imageData.shape)
```

Does your object detection model need color images or can you convert the 1 channel (gray scale) array to a 3 channel array?  I think you have a problem if you need color images -- I don't think you can reverse the process. You user will have to save the images as 3 channel RGB arrays.

If you just need a 3 channel array, you can expand the 1 channel array as shown below.

```
imageData3x = np.stack((imageData,imageData,imageData),axis=2)
print('3x Grey scale image:',imageData3x.dtype, imageData3x.shape)

plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(imageData3x)
plt.show()
```

Note: the code above does not deal with the other data transformations in the HDF5 file (conversion to `np.uint16` and multiplying the values by 8). It's not clear to me why either of those were done. However, they would be simple enough to "undo", so long as you have a tag to know `if convertTo16Bit` was `True` or `False`.